# How do you get start-of-period and end-of-period datetime values that a datetime is in?

Tags: python, pandas

Putting the question another way: Does pandas have a way to get the bin/window limits that a particular datetime would get included in, were that datetime to be part of an index that was getting resampled?

The various resampling frequencies (like `Q-JUL` for quarter ending in July) are extremely useful, and it would be nice to be able to get the bounds that a single window fits in so it could be used in a filter.  For example: "Filter results to include only those results that are in the same time window as X."

I'm looking for a function something like this fabricated one(`pd.get_datetime_limits(rule, dt)`:

```
>>> pd.get_datetime_limits("A", datetime(2014, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59))
(datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59))
>>> pd.get_datetime_limits("A", datetime(2015, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1))
(datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59))
```

ie: jump the test point across the bounds of a year and you get different limits.

Note: I'm quite certain that the upper/lower bounds in that example aren't the correct ones as far as which end is inclusive and not, but they are there to illustrate the point.  Also, wanting to get the exact matching pandas-determined bounds is a big reason for wanting the function in the first place!

Answer (score 1):

For a specific Period you can use `start_time` and `end_time` (reusing some of JAB's example):

```
In [11]: rng = pd.date_range('2015-01-01', periods=5, freq='42D')

In [12]: df = pd.DataFrame({'value': np.arange(5)}, index=rng)

In [13]: pi = df.index.to_period("Q-JUL")

In [14]: pi[0]
Out[14]: Period('2015Q2', 'Q-JUL')

In [15]: pi[0].start_time
Out[15]: Timestamp('2014-11-01 00:00:00')

In [16]: pi[0].end_time
Out[16]: Timestamp('2015-01-31 23:59:59.999999999')
```

For the entire PeriodIndex use `to_timestamp`:

```
In [17]: pi.to_timestamp(how='start')
Out[17]:
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2014-11-01, ..., 2015-05-01]
Length: 5, Freq: None, Timezone: None

In [18]: pi.to_timestamp(how='end')
Out[18]:
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2015-01-31, ..., 2015-07-31]
Length: 5, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
#set up frame with datatime index at 7d intervals
rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=1000, freq='7D')
df = pd.DataFrame({'value':range(1,1001),'date':rng})
df.set_index('date', inplace =True)

#define your rule
Rule = 'Q-JUL'
Date = '2011-03-30'
```

Then apply the rule to the datatime index, and to a datetime object using 'to_period` for filtering:

```
df1 = df[df.index.to_period(Rule) == pd.to_datetime(Date).to_period(Rule)]
```

If you want the `min()` and `max()`:

```
df1.index.min()
df1.index.max()
```